# How to send the push notificationn in flutter without console

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter

Is their any way to implement the push notification in flutter using firebase cloud messaging without firebase console. I want to send the notification to to the flutter application using javascript. Means all the message data  is filled using javascript and it uses the firebase cloud messaging to send the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Cloud Messaging API to send notifications from any code to your mobile app.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest